# JDBC connection problem

Tags: jdbc, connection

i have created only one object for connection MYSQL database ... and i am trying to access it only one time but it is giving a exception like this

Could not able to connect database com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Too many connections

please help me out to this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the value of the `max_connections` variable in your `my.cnf` file? Are there other users connecting to the same MySQL server?

Comment: dont know about this... the server is located in other place .... is there any way to know who are connected with this MYSQL  server